# One word verb meaning "making use of currently unused resources"

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, titles

I'm looking for a verb to be a project name (i.e. Project <Verb>). The project is basically about making use (or getting value from) a bunch of resources we have that are currently not being utilized.

Some I've thought of are "Leverage", "Exploit", "Capitalise" but they all have slightly negative connotations (and also are a bit "business jargony" which I want to avoid.) I want to get across the idea of using idle capacity.

Another option is to name it after a person / event which has a clear link to the project purpose. (e.g. We have "Project Giuliani", relating to a zero-tolerance project to eliminate minor inefficiencies, pertaining to his zero-tolerance approach to cleaning up NYC.)

Comment: Maximise, re-mobilise?

Comment: Thanks @Spagirl -  I like re-mobilise, except the resources in question have never been used before. Mobilise is a good option, except that it may make people think of mobile phones (as they are IT projects, and mobiles are one of the IT services we provide). Any synonyms for mobilise? (I think that's the closest match to what I'm thinking so far!)

Comment: Maybe "Project Galvanise"? It's about getting people to use these unused resources, so that could work.

Comment: Does it have to be one word? Project Bring-off-the-Bench could have a sporting rah-rah air to it rather than being all business-y

Comment: Oooh - I like that one, too!

Comment: You might want to hit up a thesaurus to see if there are any synonyms for _Leverage_, _Exploit_, or _Capitalize_ that suit your needs.

Comment: Project *Benefit*?  Project *Utilize*?  By the way, I question the decision to use a verb.  Seems like a noun coming from a verb might be better, e.g. Project *Utilization*.

Comment: I like Project Utilization - that works well. Have to confess, though, I went with Galvanise (off the back of @Spagirl 's suggestion of Mobilise.) Looking back this doesn't necessarily fit my brief as well as some of the other suggestions here, as I neglected to mention the biggest challenge of the project was getting people to use these unused resources (hence Galvanising the users into action). Not sure what etiquette is on here with regards to accepting an answer as they have all been excellent suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

I like Capitalize, but if you are looking for others...

> **Cultivate**
> [kuhl-tuh-veyt]/
> verb (used with object), cultivated, cultivating.
>
> 1. to prepare and work on (land) in order to raise crops; till.
> 2. to use a cultivator on.
> 3. to promote or improve the growth of (a plant, crop, etc.) by labor and attention.
> 4. to develop or improve by education or training; train; refine:
> 5. to promote the growth or development of (an art, science, etc.); foster.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that occurred actually was the saying in French "S'il pleut en Juin, mange ton foin" literally if it rains in June, use up your hay. I mention this since it implies that the context is important. "Use up" does not fit your pithy aim, but how about "Project Engage" - it has a technical flavour, engaging gears, setting a machine in motion, getting things accomplished.

Answer (score -1):

How about "Project ***Tap***", as in "The miners tapped into a vein they weren't aware of."

From Shorter Oxford English dictionary (definition 3d):

> tap (verb):  *figurative* establish trade or communication with, obtain information, supplies, or resources from.

Answer (score -2):

The words like Potentialize or Invigorate may be used to make sense here.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. StackExchange seeks to provide *definitive* answers, not unsupported opinions or suggestions. *Why* do you think these words make sense? What are some examples of their usage? What is the difference between them? I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.